# Why is Bundle not suitable for large data, and ViewModel is?

Tags: android, bundle, viewmodel

I read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#viewmodel_vs_savedinstancestate), and it says:

> For simple data, the activity can use the onSaveInstanceState() method
>   and restore its data from the bundle in onCreate(), but this approach
>   is only suitable for small amounts of data that can be serialized then
>   deserialized, not for potentially large amounts of data like a list of
>   users or bitmaps.

My question is why? How does the ViewModel differs from Bundle with regards to making the data persistent between instances?

Comment: For large data sets to be visible across activities(or fragments), the app has to perform serialization and deserialization and this process can cause lag in loading data. The main reason is that these data-sets are most probably a model class, in general apps. And as you'd have noticed, a bundle only accepts transient models for storage(be it parcelable or serializable) and thus, when you store data in a bundle the models are converted into transient data and when an activity or fragment is restored, the models are deserialized. The larger the data-set, the more time for acquiring data-set.

Comment: @Jay I think this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Jay put it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Jay Thanks man for the info. I was also stuck with viewmodel object and Serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Data stored in `Bundle` is serializable and could survive process die - you can restore it after application is launched again. On the other side, `ViewModel` only survive during `configuration change` (for example, rotation of the screen) and didn't save it's data if component die.

Answer (score 0):

[**Bundle**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) is class used to pass data between components of android like activities, fragments etc.

**Mainly for activity**, when activity is under any configuration changes, bundle helps to save some small amount of user data to be restored on new configuration applied. Due to limited memory provided for any App, it's stated that,

> *this approach is only suitable for small amounts of data that can be serialized then deserialized, not for potentially large amounts of
>   data like a list of users or bitmaps*.

Also, it is not anything related to activity lifecycle.

From [**ViewModel guide**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), it's stated that

> The `ViewModel` class is designed to store and manage **UI-related
>   data** in a **lifecycle** conscious way. The `ViewModel` class allows
>   data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.

So, any data which you need to survive any configuration changes can be part of `ViewModel` class, it can be any large amount of data.

*Let me know if still confused, hope it helps !*

---

**Edit** :

Thin line difference is

Bundle is something which is provided by activity once it's under configuration change. So, the **OS** parcels the underlying Bundle of the intent. Then, the OS creates the new activity (yes, it's new object of same activity), **un-parcels** the data, and passes the intent to the new activity.

ViewModel objects are something that are provided by `ViewModelFactory` which is out of context for activity & it doesn't rely on activity instance.

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference in persistance strategies - the VM is part of the app so also subjected to limited memory. How do Bundle way of saving the data differs than that of VM ?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli please check, let me know if still confused.